# php multi dimension sort by string

Tags: php, sorting

I want to sort array in descending order using php.

like `'XXS','XS','S','M','L','XL','2X','3X','4X','5X','6','7','8','9','10','11'`

`$attributesData['attributes'][$key]['options'][$search]` this will return following array value and its store to `$data['attributes'][$key]` this array before its store I want to sort by `label` in `$data['attributes'][$key]` array.

```
Array
(
    [id] => 68
    [label] => 2X
)
Array
(
    [id] => 69
    [label] => 3X

)
Array
(
    [id] => 72
    [label] => L
)
Array
(
    [id] => 73
    [label] => M
)
```

I tried many way but not getting proper solution.

Comment: shouldn't it be `... '5X','4X','3X','2X', ...` ? if we talk about descending order

Comment: yes you are rigth but I have numbers of array like this

Comment: It [***was***](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41458398/1) a good question. You have your answer; Now start implementing instead of requesting the red carpet.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
$sizes = ['XXS' => 16, 'XS' => 15, 'S' => 14, 'M' => 13, 'L' => 12, 'XL' => 11, '2X' => 10, '3X' => 9, '4X' => 8, '5X' => 7, '6' => 6, '7' => 5, '8' => 4, '9' => 3, '10' => 2, '11' => 1];

usort($myArray, function($a, $b) use ($sizes) {
    if ($a['label'] == $b['label']) {
        return 0;
    }

    return $sizes[$a['label']] < $sizes[$b['label']] ? -1 : 1;
});

var_dump($myArray);
```

Comment: Missed `usort`. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. It should **sort** in any order define in the `array`.

```
// Array of labels in order
$order = ['XXS','XS','S','M','L','XL','2X','3X','4X','5X','6','7','8','9','10','11'];
// values
$array =[
[
    'id' => 68,
    'label' => '2X',
],
[
    'id' => 69,
    'label' => '3X',

],
[
    'id' => 72,
    'label' => 'L',
],
[
    'id' => 73,
    'label' => 'M',
]];

$new = [];
foreach($order as $o) {
   // Get the index of the label in values
   $pos = array_search($o, array_column($array, 'label'));
   // If found store in new array
   if($pos !== false) {
      $new[] = $array[$pos];
   }
}

var_dump($new);
```

**Output**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(73)
    ["label"]=>
    string(1) "M"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(72)
    ["label"]=>
    string(1) "L"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(68)
    ["label"]=>
    string(2) "2X"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(69)
    ["label"]=>
    string(2) "3X"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/708904)

Answer (score 1):

use the usort to sort them.

```
$size = ['XXS','XS','S','M','L','XL','2X','3X','4X','5X','6','7','8','9','10','11'];
$weight = array_flip($size);
$result = usort($sortSize, function($a, $b) use($weight){return $weight[$b['label']] > $weights[$a['label']];});
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this may work

```
    <?php

$a = Array(
    1 => Array(
         'id' => 68,
         'label' => '2X'
    ),
    0 => Array(
         'id' => 69,
         'label' => '3X'
    ),
    2 => Array(
         'id' => 70,
         'label' => 'L'
    ),
     3 => Array(
         'id' => 71,
         'label' => 'XXS'
    ),
    4 => Array(
         'id' => 72,
         'label' => '11'
    ),
    5 => Array(
         'id' => 72,
         'label' => 'M'
    ),
);
function compareByName($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a["label"], $b["label"]);
}
usort($a, 'compareByName');
print_r(array_reverse($a)); ?>
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/708956)